# How to mock a computed property, when testing a Vue3 component with Jest

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, vuejs3, computed-properties

## Situation

I am trying to test a simple Vue3 component with Jest. I want to evaluate whether a certain text is rendered. The decision is dependent on a boolean computed value (`isNeverShowAgain`), and **I want to mock that computed value**.

```
<template>
    <div :class="{ modal: true, 'is-active': showDialog }">
    ....
                <WelcomeText />
    ....
    </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
    ....
export default defineComponent({
    name: 'WelcomeMessage',
    components: { WelcomeText },
    data() {
        return {
            /** Whether to show the message this time*/
            showDialog: false,
    ....
        };
    },
    beforeMount() {
        //Decide whether to actually show this dialog now, before mounting it, to avoid any flicker
        this.showDialog = !this.isNeverShowAgain === true;
    },
    ....
    computed: {
        /** Whether the welcome message has been permanently dismissed */
        isNeverShowAgain(): boolean {
            return this.$store.getters.neverShowWelcomeMessageAgain;
        },
    },
});
</script>
```

Like shown above, in the real world this computed value (`isNeverShowAgain`) is taken from a vuex store property, and this is where I am stuck. There are many posts that show how to mock the vuex store, but this seems overkill to me.

## Question

**How can I mock the `isNeverShowAgain` computed value, without mocking the complete vuex store?**

## Context

Here is my failing test:

```
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 * @devdoc See https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils-next/issues/194#issue-689186727 about the setup with "as any"
 */

import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import WelcomeMessage from '@/components/WelcomeMessage.vue';

describe('WelcomeMessage.vue', () => {
    it('should display the message', () => {
        const wrapper = mount(WelcomeMessage, {
            computed: {
                isNeverShowAgain() {
                    return false;
                },
            },
        } as any);
        // wrapper.vm.setComputed({ isNeverShowAgain: false }); //Deprecated and does not work

        // Assert the rendered text of the component
        expect(wrapper.text()).toContain('Welcome');
    });
});
```

Here is the error I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getters' of undefined

  69 |         /** Whether the welcome message has been permanently dismissed */
  70 |         isNeverShowAgain(): boolean {
> 71 |             return this.$store.getters.neverShowWelcomeMessageAgain;
     |                                ^
  72 |         },
  73 |     },
  74 | });
```

It's obvious that the problem is a not mocked vuex store, but again, how can I mock the computed value, that depends on the store in the first place?

## Notes

Remember, this is Vue3 and the matching Jest2 test utils, so some previously available  features are now deprecated like setComputed.

My dependencies

```
"devDependencies": {
    .....
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.2",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0-rc.16",
    "@vue/vue3-jest": "^27.0.0-alpha.3",
    "jest": "^27.3.1",
    "jest-cli": "^27.3.1",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.7",
    "ts-node": "^10.4.0",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5",
},
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to mock the computed but you have to mock the store like this:

```
const wrapper = mount(WelcomeMessage, {
    $mocks: {
      $store: {
        getters: { 
           neverShowWelcomeMessageAgain: true
        }
      }    
    }
});
```